# Migrating From a Combined Hand Crafted Website and WordPress to Only WordPress

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I've migrated a hand crafted website to WordPress website. The previous implementation did have WordPress in a sub directory for a blog. Apparently the admin for the blog was not the owner of the website, I couldn't get the admin username and password from the owner so I couldn't use the duplicator plugin. Due to time constriction I was not able to merge the blog into the new website prior to removing the active blog.

I have all the files and the database (in database.sql form) from the previous version of the website.

I have found the database table diagram at [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description), but I'm most interested in the minimal number of tables necessary to transfer.

**What tables from the old database do I need to import into the new database (after changing all the absolute links to the correct addresses)?**

I know about the wp_postmeta table and wp_posts table, are there any others I need to import.

Comment: If you have access to the database you can change the admin users email address to your own and then request a password reset. After you've successfully logged in as an admin use a duplicator/migration plugin that will handle updating all the URLs in the database for you. Depending on your situation you may just want to export the content with the default WordPress exporter tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what data you want to preserve.

The main data types and tables are:

- Terms (wp_term_relationships, wp_term_taxonomy, wp_termmeta, wp_terms)
- Comments (wp_comments, wp_commentmeta)
- Users (wp_users, wp_usermeta)

Do you not want to just import the whole `.sql` file and start from there? That might be easier than trying to piece things together. You could then drop any table than doesn't being with `wp_` (or whatever prefix you used).

Comment: That probably would have been a good way to start if the owner wasn't in a hurry, but I've already got the website up and running without the blog.